# Keeping user logged in - single page application (spa)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a single page application which uses facebook JS SDK to authenticate users. What would be a good solution to keep the user logged in without having to refresh the page?

I was thinking of maybe setting an interval which calls the following function every 60 min or so:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(callbackFunction, true);
```